# How to set state in test when using enzyme and jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

To start I'm conditionally rendering a component that's reliant on the useState hook being set as a result of useEffect hook. Here's a code sample:

```js
function Component() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();
  const [fail, setFail] = useState();
  /**
   * @function getModels - fetch data to populate the models
   * */
  const fetchStuff = async () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then((data) => {
        const storage = [data];
        setResponse(storage);
        setFail(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setResponse(err);
        setFail(true);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStuff();
  }, []);

  if (fail === true) {
    return (
      <p>
        ERROR:
        {fail}
      </p>
    );
  }
  if (fail === false) {
    return (
      <p>
        Success:
        {response}
      </p>
    );
  }
  return <p>Loading Screen</p>;
}
```

My current point of contention is that I'm unable to call setResponse or setFail and update the state of fail or response. I believe that I need to use mount as opposed to shallow rendering? Also, I understand that testing philosophies would argue against conducting a test in this fashion. However, I am seeking an a solution that enables updating the state. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So, I found a solution here:

https://dev.to/theactualgivens/testing-react-hook-state-changes-2oga

But this updates the state of both useState hooks. Is there a means of setting each useState hook independently?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57025753/how-to-set-initial-state-for-usestate-hook-in-jest-and-enzyme

The comment from Jimmy links to mockImplementationOnce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mock `fetch` API call to and its resolved value. Then, you can assert what exactly the component renders. We should use `whenStable` function to make sure the mocked API calls are completed.

`Component.jsx`:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function Component() {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState();
  const [fail, setFail] = useState();
  /**
   * @function getModels - fetch data to populate the models
   * */
  const fetchStuff = async () => {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
      .then((data) => {
        const storage = [data];
        setResponse(storage);
        setFail(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        setResponse(err);
        setFail(true);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchStuff();
  }, []);

  if (fail === true) {
    return (
      <p>
        ERROR:
        {fail}
      </p>
    );
  }
  if (fail === false) {
    return (
      <p>
        Success:
        {response}
      </p>
    );
  }
  return <p>Loading Screen</p>;
}
```

`Component.test.jsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Component } from './Component';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { act } from 'react-dom/test-utils';

const whenStable = async () => {
  await act(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
  });
};

describe('65243384', () => {
  let fetch;
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch = global.fetch;
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    global.fetch = fetch;
  });
  it('should success', async () => {
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce('mocked success data');
    const wrapper = mount(<Component></Component>);
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('Loading Screen');
    await whenStable();
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('Success:mocked success data');
    expect(global.fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  });

  it('should fail', async () => {
    const mErr = new Error('network');
    global.fetch = jest.fn().mockRejectedValueOnce(mErr);
    const wrapper = mount(<Component></Component>);
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('Loading Screen');
    await whenStable();
    expect(wrapper.find('p').text()).toBe('ERROR:');
    expect(global.fetch).toBeCalledWith('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  examples/65243384/Component.test.jsx
  65243384
    ✓ should success (44 ms)
    ✓ should fail (5 ms)

---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File           | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files      |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 Component.jsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
---------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        5.121 s
```

source code: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-v26-codelab/tree/main/examples/65243384